# My field is null for a record and the field name not even showing in system.debug? How can I make it appear?

Tags: apex

I created a dummy object TestObject__c and 1 number field with 2 records. 1st record is having some value and in 2nd no value. However, when I ran the system.debug for number field, the field doesn't even show up for 2nd record, I was expecting it to return at least 'null' value but field itself is not coming in system.debug. How to show up the field even for 'no value'?

Comment: do check out [ask]

Comment: Please [edit] your post to provide a complete code example with output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this debugging code in an Anonymous Apex window (from developer console its command+e or control+e).  Additionally, replace `YourNumberField__c` with the api name of the number field that you alluded to.

```
List<TestObject__c> testObjList = new List<TestObject__c>([SELECT Id,Name,YourNumberField__c FROM TestObject__c])
System.debug('testObjList.size() is '+ testObjList.size());

for (TestObject__c record: testObjList){
System.debug('Id:'+record.Id + 'has number field value: '+record.YourNumberField__c);
}
```